# Requesting metadata with Socrata API

Tags: api, dataset, socrata, soda

Each dataset published with Socrata has its "About" page. For example:

- https://data.cityofchicago.org/Buildings/Building-Permits/ydr8-5enu/about

But docs at [dev.socrata.com](https://dev.socrata.com/) don't mention how I can request this metadata with their API.

I tried requesting `about.json`, but no avail.

Socrata's Open Data Network features docs for each dataset. In this case,

- https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofchicago.org/9pkb-4fbf

But its "about" page contains only data scheme:

- http://www.opendatanetwork.com/dataset/data.cityofchicago.org/9pkb-4fbf

So, is it possible to get the original "About" page via API?

Comment: What metadata are you looking to get from the about page? Column metadata, or details like name and description? Do you want to get them in bulk, or just for that one dataset?

Comment: @chrismetcalf Ideally, in bulk for all datasets. The field of interest are "Visits" and "Downloads".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out the Socrata Labs "Catalog" API?

http://labs.socrata.com/docs/search.html

That includes most of the metadata as well as the view counts for each dataset. You can filter it down to just Chicago data using the `domain=` filter:

http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domain=data.cityofchicago.org